# How can I import more code completion in vim?

Tags: vim

I program using java and vim and I want to figure out how to do code completion in vim. I downloaded the vim plugin javacompletion and it works, but it only for j2se but not for android source code.

Is there any code completion in vim for andriod source code? I would like that when I, for example, enter "TextView." (the class in android.jar) and press ctrl+x ctrl+o, it should show the functions in TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at [Vjde](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1213) vim plugin.

I remember using it before and you just have to tell it to also look inside android.jar for the stuff to autocomplete.